# Why do I keep getting expected identifier or '('?

Tags: c, identifier

I am new but ready to learn.

Can anybody tell me why does expected identifier or '(' keep appearing for the following code?

```
1 /* $Id: simple_pjsua.c 3553 2011-05-05 06:14:19Z nanang $ */
2 /*
3  *
```

The full code can be found in the following link: http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/page_pjsip_sample_simple_pjsuaua_c.htm

Comment: You got rid of the line numbers (like that leading "1") before compiling, right?  If so, the only reason that error should occur there is if you're trying to compile C with a non-C compiler.

Comment: Don't copy the line numbers.

Comment: what language are we talking here about? And when you do what?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you didn't delete the line numbers.

The line numbers on that web page are for the (alleged) convenience of the reader. They're not valid C syntax.

BTW, it would have been useful to show us the full exact error message.  I got:

```
error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
```

The "numeric constant" would have been a big clue.